# Inbound emails domain with Mandrill

Tags: email, mandrill

I am using the Mandrill mail server for sending emails to users and I have my own domain added to Mandrill to send out mails. Suppose I have configured Mandrill to use `info@mydomain.com` to send out emails and then it should send emails which it does. And any replies sent to `info@mydomain.com` will be forwarded to traditional mailboxes.

Now I have a doubt on receiving emails via Mandrill, once I add an inbound domain and route its path to my desired location, it should be ready to receive emails. Well I have read questions on SO and it has been said that if someone wants to use traditional mailboxes for receiving mails then it's better not to use Mandrill or use a custom sub domain.

Also it has been said that it is not possible for Mandrill to receive email which is already configured or forwarded to some other traditional mailboxes.

So I added a sub domain to Mandrill's inbound domain like `inbound.mydomain.com` and receive emails on this domain which will be received by Mandrill and will be send to the desired route which we set up. Now I will have to change my sender domain with the same that is `inbound.mydomain.com` to make users reply to this domain which will be received at Mandrill. What I want is :

1. Send emails using `info@mydomain.com`
2. Receive emails to my location using inbound domains

Comment: This isn't really an ExpressionEngine question (this is the ExpressionEngine SE). Whilst someone here may be able to help you it's more likely you would receive a better answer from either Mandrill's support or the more general StackOverflow site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mandrill with no reference to ExpressionEngine.